# How to read a property value of json file located local on Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a json file like below:

```
{
  "result": {
    "covered_percent": 47.06
  }
}
```

and how can I read this value on Ubuntu Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of ubuntu but as a 1 liner from the terminal this works for me (assumes json file is in same directory and called json_file.json)

```
python -c "import json;print json.loads(open('json_file.json', 'r').read())['result']['covered_percent']"
```

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.10 and this was very useful for me. Thank you so much GreenGuerilla

Comment: I can get this value but I coundn't set a variable with this value like this $ cVal = python -c "import json;print json.loads(open('.last_run.json', 'r').read())['result']['covered_percent']". I get "No command 'cVal' found" error when I try to set. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi Pegatron - sounds like you need to export the shell variable... We are talking bash, right?

Comment: Try this: export cVal=`python -c "import json;print json.loads(open('json_file.json', 'r').read())['result']['covered_percent']"`

Comment: Ok problem - stackoverflow formatting issues: You need to wrap the whole python -c "code, etc..." with these characters: `

Comment: Two of those wrapping everything from the start of the python command right to the end

Comment: Then cVal is available as $cVal

Comment: If I were you I would write a python script. This is getting kind of messy!!

Comment: I putted the this char: ` and It worked really like a charm :) I needed the shell variable and the easiest way is this for me. I got the value. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 4):

As a shorter one liner you can use the following:

```
cat some_file.json | python -mjson.tool
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `jq` is another option:

```
$ val=( $(jq '.result.covered_percent' my_file.json))
$ echo $val
47.06
```